# How to implement universal deeplinking in iOS for twiter and Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, twitter, ios-universal-links

I want to implement universal linking in iOS Swift for twitter & Facebook.I tried with native way of creating universal linking file and keep it on our server. This is only working with WhatsApp, Mail and Notes but not working on Facebook, twitter and LinkedIn. I found that Facebook is not allowing to open app from there but why twitter and linkedin is not allowing.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Universal Links do not work in Facebook and Twitter. You need to use [Facebook App Links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks) and [Twitter App Cards](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/app-card). The reason is that these apps can control what URLs they open in and out of the app, so they force you to adhere to their standards to deep link out of their apps.